# RealmSwift is requiring Realm also

Tags: swift, realm, genome

I am migrating a project to Swift 3 and have encountered some issues with RealmSwift (2.6.1) and Genome (3.2.0). I'm getting errors for Realm in Xcode that say I need these inits:

```
required convenience init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
    self.init(realm: realm, schema: schema)
}

required convenience init(value: Any, schema: RLMSchema) {
    self.init(value: value, schema: schema)
}
```

However, that requires importing Realm in addition to RealmSwift, and when my class is initialized it is trying to use an RLMRealm instead of a Realm. The warning says 'required' initializer 'init(realm:schema:)' must be provided by subclass of 'Object', but that required init uses RLMRealm not Realm  Any suggestions?

I am using Genome as well which requires this init, which is why Realm is asking for initializers in the first place:

```
required convenience init(node: Node, in context: Context) throws {
    self.init()
}
```

So inits look like this all together:

```
class BaseModel : RealmSwift.Object, MappableBase, Identifiable {

required init() {
    super.init()
}

required convenience init(node: Node, in context: Context) throws {
    self.init()
}

required convenience init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
    self.init(realm: realm, schema: schema)
}

required convenience init(value: Any, schema: RLMSchema) {
    self.init(value: value, schema: schema)
}
```

Everything worked fine in Swift 2.3 (using the corresponding Swift 2.3 versions of Realm and Genome) without any of these initializers, but now it is not working.

Entire Model:

```
import RealmSwift
import Genome
import Realm

protocol Identifiable {
    var identifier: String { get set }
}


class BaseModel : RealmSwift.Object, MappableBase, Identifiable {

required init() {
    super.init()
}

required convenience init(node: Node, in context: Context) throws {
    try self.init(node: node, in: context)
}

required convenience init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
    self.init(realm: realm, schema: schema)
}

required convenience init(value: Any, schema: RLMSchema) {
    self.init(value: value, schema: schema)
}

dynamic var identifier = ""
dynamic var updatedAt: Date?

override static func primaryKey() -> String {
    return "identifier"
}

static func newInstance(_ node: Node, context: Context = EmptyNode) throws -> Self {
    let map = Map(node: node, in: context)
    let new = self.init()
    try new.sequence(map)
    return new
}

func sequence(_ map: Map) throws {
    switch map.type {
    case .fromNode:
        if self.identifier.isEmpty {
            // only map id if there isn't one, otherwise Realm complains about modified primaryKey
            try self.identifier <~ map["id"]
        }
        updatedAt = Date()
    case .toNode:
        if !self.identifier.isEmpty {
            try self.identifier ~> map["id"]
        }
    }
}

func objectRepresentation() -> [String : AnyObject] {
    if let result = try? self.toObject() {
        return result as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
    } else {
        return [:]
    }
}

static func objectInRealm(_ realm: Realm, identifier: String?) -> Self? {
    if let identifier = identifier {
        return realm.object(ofType: self, forPrimaryKey: identifier)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

static func createOrFindObject(inRealm realm: Realm, identifier: String) -> Self {
    if let foundObject = realm.object(ofType: self, forPrimaryKey: identifier) {
        return foundObject
    } else {
        return realm.create(self, value: ["identifier" : identifier], update: false)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did you happen to declare any non-Optional, uninitialized properties in the class?

Comment: No, I checked that already but good thinking.

Comment: Typically, required initializers need to be overridden only when something _in your class_ needs to be initialized, like properties.

Comment: Right, but I need a required initializer to conform to NodeInitializable protocol for Gemone

Comment: Please edit your question and provide us with the entire model.

Comment: @WillowPuge done!

Comment: The warning says 'required' initializer 'init(realm:schema:)' must be provided by subclass of 'Object', but that required init uses RLMRealm not Realm

Comment: @WillowPuge do you or anyone else at Realm have any insight on this?

Comment: Would you be able to open a GitHub issue on https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/new and reference this stack overflow post? Please provide as much information as possible and fill out the issue template. This _may_ be a bug in Realm or it could be something in your code or setup. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to override `init(realm:schema:)` and `init(realm:schema:)`, just define `convenience required init(node:in:) throws` like the following.

```
class BaseModel : RealmSwift.Object, MappableBase, Identifiable {

    convenience required init(node: Node, in context: Context) throws {
        try self.init(node: node, in: context)
    }

    ...

}
```